# Make a sphere from a circle of dots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, geometry

I have a circle [a circle from dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P81dl.png)
Now I need make a sphere.
Could someone help me with it.
I think i have to use x**2 + y**2 + z**2 <= R**2 and use Axes3D module.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = list(range(1, 101))
Y = list(range(1, 101))


x = numpy.array(X)
y = numpy.array(Y)

xgrid, ygrid = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

filter = (xgrid-50)**2 + (ygrid-50)**2 <= 25**2
ax.scatter(xgrid[filter], ygrid[filter], s= 1, color='green')

ax.set_title('сетка из точек 100х100',
            fontfamily = 'monospace',
            fontstyle = 'normal',
            fontweight = 'bold',
            fontsize = 10)
ax.set_xlabel("Value", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Square of Value", fontsize=14)

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)

ax.axis([0, 101, 0, 101])

plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want a sphere of given radius R?
If true, how should the internal points be decided? In a rectangular grid?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? I don't recommend plotting that much points though, it is quite heavy, try plotting less points (like in the code comments)...

Also try not using 'filter', it is a reserved keyword in Python

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define sphere parameters
cX, cY, cZ = 50, 50, 50
radius = 25

x = np.array(range(0, 101))
y = np.array(range(0, 101))
z = np.array(range(0, 101))

# try that instead, it is less heavy
# x = np.array(range(0, 101, 5))
# y = np.array(range(0, 101, 5))
# z = np.array(range(0, 101, 5))

xgrid, ygrid, zgrid = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

check = (xgrid - cX)**2 + (ygrid - cY)**2 + (zgrid - cZ)**2 <= radius**2
ax.scatter(xgrid[check], ygrid[check], zgrid[check], color='green')

ax.set_title('сетка из точек 100х100',
            fontfamily = 'monospace',
            fontstyle = 'normal',
            fontweight = 'bold',
            fontsize = 10)
ax.set_xlabel("Value", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Square of Value", fontsize=14)

ax.set_xlim3d(0, 101)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 101)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 101)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you Tartempion for your help! And thank you for your advice about using a reserved keyword 'filter'!